# Applescript forward/rewind NowPlaying in menu bar

Tags: applescript, macos-big-sur, apple-m1

I'm looking for a way to compile two scripts on Big Sur that will allow me to fastforward and rewind 5 sec. any video currently playing in the NowPlaying widget, the one in the menu bar [see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgL2i.png).

[image]

I tried to locate the correct path using UI browser, but it doesn't seem to work. Here's the path to it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/noYL0.jpg.

[image]